# Suggession on Line Chart

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, line, charts

I have a requirement to create Chart like this :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ecgtoolkit-cs/

I have to be very specific on how much data it needs to display per unit in graph. I can do it using manual Drawing, but is there any easy way to build this without doing it manually?

I am thinking about the alternatives.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can it be paid solution? I've used Telerik for asp.net ajax, but they have win forms too http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/chart.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ZedGraph](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx) will do the job.  It's easy to setup and make exactly what you want and you can control the data through the IPointList classes.

The only negative is the current lack of support, however there's a lot of info in the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20090410072128/http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page), as well as support board at [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/)

Answer (score 0):

Telerik is a reliable and high quality control maker. Alot of people will attest to the quality and ease of development with [Telerik Rad Controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx).